# Auto shutdown script with an option to cancel the user called from task scheduler

Tags: windows, powershell, deployment, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to set up a scheduled task for our office staff that will shut down the computer at a pre-set time.

I already have a script that hard shuts down at 11:00 with no option to the user.

However, to help with our energy saving systems I would like to shut down earlier in the evening, but give any late workers the option to hold off the shutdown.

It works when I run it from the PowerShell terminal but, when it's in the scheduled task it stops working.

Is there any limit to PowerShell scripts being run from a scheduled task?
Is there a native way to ask for user permission to shut down? Would it be easier to use a Bat file?

I have set up the sheduled tasks with the Argument code like this. The username is a active directory admin.

```
$taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction `
    -Execute 'powershell.exe' `
    -Argument '\Users\deployment\docs\RequestPowerOff-GUI.ps1'

$taskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 09:00PM #not for roll out

Register-ScheduledTask `
    -TaskName $taskName `
    -Action $taskAction `
    -Trigger $taskTrigger `
    -Description $description `
    -User $UserName -Password $Password
```

And the code that is to be run from the ps1 file is this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

shutdown -s -t 600 -f

$answer = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show( "Computer will Auto Shutdown in 10 min. Would you like to continue working?", "Auto Shutdown ", "YesNo", "Warning" )

if ($answer -eq "Yes")
{
    shutdown -a
    [void] [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show( "poweroff canceled", "Auto poweroff", "OK", "Information" )
    
}
```

Comment: What user or principal are you running the task under? What does your call to `Register-ScheduledTask` look like?

Comment: Thanks @zdan . added a section to the register. The account that is used is an AD Admin.

Answer (score 1):

By using [`Register-ScheduledTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/register-scheduledtask)'s `-User` and `-Password` parameters you're launching the scheduled task *via a service*, which means that it cannot interact with the user's desktop and can therefore not a present a UI to the user.

To allow such interaction, you must create a principal object with [`New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtaskprincipal) and `-LogonType Interactive`, which means that the task will run (a) only when that user is logged on and (b) will then run *visibly*, allowing you to present a UI:

- Note: Unless you're scheduling the task for *yourself*, the following code must be run *with elevation* (as admin).

```
$taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction `
    -Execute 'powershell.exe' `
    -Argument '\Users\deployment\docs\RequestPowerOff-GUI.ps1'

$taskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 09:00PM #not for roll out

# Create a principal with -LogonType Interactive (which is actually the default)
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId $UserName -LogonType Interactive

# Instead of using -UserName and -Password, pass the $principal object
# to -Principal
Register-ScheduledTask `
    -TaskName $taskName `
    -Action $taskAction `
    -Trigger $taskTrigger `
    -Description $description `
    -Principal $principal
```